# jQuery conflcits: Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I've just recently added Django's s3direct plugin to my website. While it works successfully on my admin page, I'm having trouble making it work on my site frontend.

Here is the page in question: http://rigsandwagons-staging.herokuapp.com/listings/add/

I keep encountering Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function, specifically when I add the following scripts at the bottom of the page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//rigsandwagons-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/static/shared-bg/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//rigsandwagons-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/static/shared-bg/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//rigsandwagons-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/static/shared-bg/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//rigsandwagons-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/static/s3direct/js/s3direct.js"></script>
```

After doing some research, I think it may have to do something with `var $s3Direct = jQuery.noConflict()` in s3direct.js, but I'm not entirely sure (as deleting that line introduced a whole host of other problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that if you define jQuery as noConflict then all your scripts that use jQuery need to reference 'jQuery' instead of '$'.

You can fix this by wrapping code that uses '$' in the following:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```

I see you've done this on line 41 in your code, just use the same technique.

Also: the error in question appears on line 661 yet you have moved code to the bottom of your file, also in a ready function. Why not move the erroneous code there too? It'll fire at the same time. I believe you'll have the same error down there too so be sure to pass the '$' through in the ready function and replace function name '$' to 'jQuery'.

With all this said, I've not used Django so this next suggestion aims to knock your thinking; If you mean to use Django then you may need to use something like this:

```
$(Django).on('ready', function() {
    // code
});
```